# How to find same variable with different value using RegEx?

Tags: regex

Here is the example.

```
0x13F4E010 = 4 new items
0x13F4E010 = 5 new items of clothing available
```

I only want to find the same variable with different value with RegEx, so i can edit it manually.

So, basically i only need help to find these duplicated variable behind different value.

```
0x13F4E010 = 
0x13F4E010 =
```

Sorry for bad english. Thank you in advance.

I find this example in internet

```
^(.*)(\W\1)+$
```

but that only find duplicate with same variable and same value. Like this...

```
    0x14C79222 = Camo Sweatpants
    0x14C79222 = Camo Sweatpants
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample regex that can do the job is

```
^(\S+) = (.+)\r?\n\1 = (.+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dkXBOQ/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `=` - a `=` with one space on both sides
- `(.+)` - Group 2: one one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF ending
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `=` - a `=` with a space on each side
- `(.+)` - Group 3: one one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$`  - end of a line.

Note you might need an `(?m)` inline regex option (or code equivalent) to make `^` and `$` match start/end of each line instead of the whole string (depends on the environment).